# Validating a hashed password field to be unique in Laravel 4.1

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I am trying to ensure that all passwords are unique. I have the following rules set up in my model:

```
public static $signup_rules = array(
    'username'  => 'required|min:6|unique:users',
    'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'password'  => 'required|min:6|unique:users'
);
```

If i try to create a new record with a username and email that already exists in the database, the validation picks it up just like it should. However, it will allow a duplicate password.

I think it is probably something to do with the fact that the password is hashed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you want your passwords to be unique? There is no need. If you were really worried about security, it would be better to enforce a level of password complexity (certainly more than '6' chars).

Comment: p.s. your problem is that the password is going to be salted - so even if two users have the 'same' password - it will look different in the database, and therefore the Laravel 'unique' rule will not work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If time you do:

```
$a = Hash::make('antonio');
$b = Hash::make('antonio');

if ($a !== $b) echo "hashes are always different!";
```

You'll see that **hashes are always different**, so using Laravel's hash system it's not possible to check if two passwords are the same.

If you want your user to use their passwords only once in your system, you'll have to check them one by one:

```
foreach(User::all() as $user)
{
    if (Hash::check($password, $user->password))
    {
       return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Which is kind of slow and crazy. And, as said in the comments, why would you need to have unique passwords in your system. This is a huge security risk because you would tell someone that there is another person in your system using that very password he thought about using.

Comment: You inverted `return true` and `return false`, but it's not the point of your answer.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, your answer makes a lot of sense. I'll just go with your suggestion of making the passwords stronger and not worry about them being unique.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a password to be unique, that is majorly overkill. However, I would suggest taking advantage of the confirm validation rule meaning you have a password_confirmation field such as

{{ Form::password('password', ['required' => 'required']) }}

{{ Form::password('password_confirmation', ['required' => 'required']) }}

and validation of:

'password'  => 'confirmed'